# Is CountDownLatch affected by spurious wakeups?

Tags: java, multithreading, countdownlatch

Concurrency management mechanisms such as wait/notify and lock/condition seem to be affected by [spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup). Developers cater for those unexpected wakeups by re-checking that the condition has indeed changed.

When it comes to CountDownLatch, are spurious wakeups an issue?

Comment: Spurious wakeups are a _documented behavior_ of wait/notify.  They are _not_ documented for CountDownLatch.   If a CountDownLatch behaves in an undocumented way, that would be a bug.  That is to say, if you implement CountDownLatch using wait/notify, then it is up to you to correctly handle a spurious wakeup, and not pass the buck to your client.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The javadoc of [`CountDownLatch#await()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await--) states

> If the current count is greater than zero then the current thread
>   becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until
>   one of two things happen:
>
> - The count reaches zero due to invocations of the `countDown()` method; or
> - Some other thread interrupts the current thread.

*dormant* meaning the method won't return. In other words, though a spurious wakeup can occur, it won't cause the `await` method to return.

You can look at the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.java#CountDownLatch.await%28%29) to see how this is done exactly, but, in brief, it's the typical trick of looping and "waiting" (through `LockSuport#park` or `Object#wait` which are affected by spurious wakeups) until a condition is met.

> When it comes to `CountDownLatch`, are spurious wakeups an issue?

No.

Answer (score 4):

The `Object.wait/Condition.await` methods are subject to "spurious wakeups".

The `await` method in `CountDownLatch` will wait until

- The count reaches zero due to invocations of the countDown() method;
  or Some other thread interrupts the current thread; or The specified
  waiting time elapses.

So evenif spurious wakeup occurs, since the count has not reached,it wont return.

So the synchronizers like `CountDownLatch`, `CyclicBarrier` etc are not subject to spurious wakeups.