# How can a CountDownLatch that is not counted down to zero return without being interrupted?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

(For posterity, I'm familiar with this other question, and its answer which would seem to suggest the case I'm observing is impossible: [Is CountDownLatch affected by spurious wakeups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573955/is-countdownlatch-affected-by-spurious-wakeups))

I have a `CountDownLatch` that is created with an `int` argument of `1`.  Deliberately, `countDown()` is never called on this latch.

I have a `ShutdownHook` that interrupts the thread that calls `myLatch.await()`, and I have a catch block that deals with the subsequent `InterruptedException`.

I'm observing that when my shutdown hook is invoked, the latch "wakes up" normally.  That is, the `await()` method returns, the thread is not interrupted, and its interrupted status (as reported by `isInterrupted()`) is `false`.

**My understanding from the `CountDownLatch` documentation is that this scenario is impossible.  What am I missing?**

The code where the latch is awaited looks like this:

```
try {
    myLatch.await();
    System.out.println("*** done via unblock");
} catch (final InterruptedException interruptedException) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    System.out.println("*** done via interrupt");
}
```

I see `*** done via unblock` when I CTRL-C my application.  My read of the documentation is that this is impossible because `CountDownLatch` instances are not subject to spurious wakeups.

The shutdown hook code looks like this:

```
// t is the thread that is doing the await() call above
final Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
      t.interrupt();
      try {
          t.join();
      } catch (final InterruptedException interruptedException) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
 }));
```

Comment: Well the interrupted status being cleared does make sense from reading the javadoc on CountDownLatch's `await()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  `InterruptedException` is never thrown.

Comment: Can you post the demo code? I used your snippets on JDK 11 and I'm getting `*** done via interrupt` when I Ctrl+C. Also, what JDK are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  JDK 8 build, uh, _checks notes_ 181.  On a Mac.  I can't post my demo code at the moment other than the excerpt above.  I take it from your comment that I'm not missing anything obvious.

Comment: @LairdNelson Honestly, I haven't tried anything else yet. Just tried running it. Tried in on JDK8 (u201) now with the same result. My test code is trivial - just a main method that defines a `new CountDownLatch(1)`, then runs your shutdownHook snippet, then your wait snippet.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to proceed under the assumption that I am _not_ seeing a spurious wakeup, but I'll be darned if I can figure out how `countDown()` is being called.  It doesn't help that `java.util.logging.LogManager` begins shutting down logs at shutdown hook time so my logging statements are useless.  Back to `System.out.println()`!

Comment: The code you've pasted doesn't compile due to a missing semicolon, so it's obviously been redacted. Are you sure you haven't redacted anything important? Try creating an MCVE with just a main that creates a latch, registers a shutdownhook, then waits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully I have found a codepath where several classes away something is indeed counting down the latch in question.  Thank goodness, since (a) my code now works and (b) the documentation is correct and spurious wakeups are in fact Not A Thing™ when we're talking about `CountDownLatch#await()`.